# Postgresql django где хранится sql код

Tags: django, postgresql

Мне нужно импортировать свою БД по ssh на хостинг, изначально была sqlite3, затем я настроил postgresql локально, однако в django проекте все равно остался файл с расширением sqlite3(я так понимаю postgres хранит sql файлы в другой папке).

Я нашел папку, где postgres хранит мою базу, но там кучу непонятных файлов без расширения, а мне для того чтобы импортировать бд нужно скопировать базу в sql файл и как сделать непонятно?

Comment: [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html), а ещё лучше [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично я использую следущий синтакс для импорта sql-файла:

```
psql -U postgres -h 127.0.0.1 my_database < my_dump_file.sql
```

Comment: да уже сделал спасибо!

Comment: Отметьте правильный ответ

Answer (score 0):

на рабочей машине выполни

```
python manage.py dumpdata > dump.json
```

На сервере

```
python manage.py loaddata dump.json
```